# How to deal with changes to ios 13 fonts?

Tags: flutter

I'm developing my first pet-project app. It's almost ready for release, but the recent ios 13 release has changed all the fonts. I can see there was an issue filed on Github (https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/43998).

My code is pretty standard:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Text(
    'Find out which bins to put out and when your collection day is',
    style: TextStyle(
      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
      fontSize: 16.0,
    ),
    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
  );
}
```

But the results are like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GaQth.jpg

How are people dealing with this?

Answer (score 0):

So, it looks like there is another Github issue to address this
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/49492